# Finding the number of irreducible quadratics in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$, where $p$ is a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The problem is to find the number of irreducible quadratics in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$, where $p$ is a prime number.

To solve this, I wish to find first the number of reducible quadratics of the form $x^2+ax+b$, then the number of reducible quadratics, and subtract this from the total number of quadtratics.

I know that each reducible quadratic that is of the form $x^2 +ax+b$ is a product $(x+c)(x+d)$ for $c,d\in \Bbb Z_p$.

So, I don't know what to do next. Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to count all irreducibles or just quadratics? Please edit either the question or the title.

Comment: Just the quadratics. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MJ. Rivo, your idea is correct. Here is how to do the calculation.

The total number of monic quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ is
$p^2$.

To see this, just note there is a bijection associating each monic quadratic polynomials $x^2 +ax+b$ to $(a,b) \in \Bbb Z_p[x] \times \Bbb Z_p[x]$.

On the other hand, the total number of **reducible** monic quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ is
$$\frac{p(p+1)}{2}.$$

To see this, just note that each reducible monic quadratic polynomial bijectively corresponds to a product $(x+c)(x+d)$ for $c,d\in \Bbb Z_p$. How many such products we have?  Since multiplication is commutative, the order does not matter. So we get $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ (for $c\neq d$) plus $p$ (for $c= d$).  The number then is $\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$.

So, the total number of **irreducible** monic quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ is
$$p^2-\frac{p(p+1)}{2}=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}.$$

So the answer for irreducible monic quadratic polynomials is $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$.

If you want the number of all irreducible quadratic polynomials (**not necessarily monic**), just note that each irreducible quadratic polynomials  bijectively corresponds to $e(x^2 +ax+b)$ where $e \in \Bbb Z_p \setminus \{0\}$ and $x^2 +ax+b$ is an irreducible monic quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$. So the total number of all irreducible quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ is
$$\frac{p(p-1)^2}{2}$$

Comment: For the part at the end about non-monic quadratics, you can't have $e=0$, so you should be multiplying by $p-1$, not $p$, right?

Comment: @nog642 Correct. Thanks for pointing it. I updated the answer.